# How to fix vmware header error?

Tags: bash, shell-script, kali-linux, vmware

I'm  trying to run vmware on my kali linux 2.0 box, because I want a lab to practice my skills on, but vmware won't launch it's giving my an error message saying "C header files matching your running kernel were not found", I ran a command to fix it but then the command spit out some error message

```
  root@kali:~# sudo apt-get install -y linux-headers-$(uname -r)
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.3.0-kali1-amd64
  E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.3.0-kali1-amd64'
  E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.3.0-kali1-amd64'
  root@kali:~#
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `apt-cache search linux-headers` or install Synaptic.  See [How do I search for available packages from the command-line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160897/how-do-i-search-for-available-packages-from-the-command-line).  Be aware that if no headers exist for whatever `uname -r` returns, you will need to upgrade, or downgrade, your kernel until you have a matching set.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have a solution for you. Recently I have installed Kali Linux on my machine and I noticed a similar issue. Executing the following `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` will only fetch form the repositories in your sources.list file. Now in my case the repositories that I have available are outdated therefore I resulted to installing the Linux Headers manually by downloading the packages then using dpkg. Here is how I accomplished that:

If your system is **32 bit**:

1) Wget the following files

```
 wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.3.4-wily/linux-headers-4.3.4-040304_4.3.4-040304.201601230132_all.deb
 wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.3.4-wily/linux-headers-4.3.4-040304-generic_4.3.4-040304.201601230132_i386.deb
 wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.3.4-wily/linux-image-4.3.4-040304-generic_4.3.4-040304.201601230132_i386.deb
```

2) Install the following packages by issuing:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.3.4*.deb linux-image-4.3.4*.deb
```

3) Reboot your system:

```
sudo reboot
```

If your system is **64 bit**:

1) Wget the following files

```
wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.3.4-wily/linux-headers-4.3.4-040304_4.3.4-040304.201601230132_all.deb
wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.3.4-wily/linux-headers-4.3.4-040304-generic_4.3.4-040304.201601230132_amd64.deb
wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.3.4-wily/linux-image-4.3.4-040304-generic_4.3.4-040304.201601230132_amd64.deb
```

2) Install the following packages by issuing:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.3.4*.deb linux-image-4.3.4*.deb
```

3) Reboot your system:

```
sudo reboot
```

If you wish to uninstall the header files issue the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove 'linux-headers-4.3.4*' 'linux-image-4.3.4*'
```